# How to close tmux session without exiting tmux?

Tags: tmux

I have several sessions in tmux

[image]

How to close/kill some of them, without exiting tmux?

If I type `exit` I am not only closing session, but also exiting tmux, which is not applicable.

Comment: `<ctrl>+b d ` detaches the current tmux session without exiting it

Comment: I need to exit it

Answer (score 6):

Apparently there's a setting for this.

In your `~/tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g detach-on-destroy off
```

Now tmux will not detach (close) when the session is destroyed, instead it will go to any other active session.

## OLD ANSWER:

I needed exactly this, as my workflow includes short-lived `tmux` sessions to jump between code projects that are killed at the end.

Since I couldn't find anything I wrote a script that switches to the first other active session before killing the current one and I bound it to <kbd>Leader</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> for quick access.

`~/.scripts/tmux-kill-session.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmux_running=$(pgrep tmux)

if [[ -z $TMUX ]] && [[ -z $tmux_running ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

session_to_kill="$(tmux list-sessions | sed -n '/(attached)/s/:.*//p')"
session_to_switch="$(tmux list-sessions | sed -n '/(attached)/!s/:.*//p' | head -n 1)"

if [[ ! -z $session_to_switch ]]; then
    tmux switch-client -t $session_to_switch 
fi

tmux kill-session -t $session_to_kill
```

`~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind X run-shell "~/.scripts/tmux-kill-session.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can kill sessions directly within tmux. Let's say you have two sessions: session1 and session2. And you're currently in session1.

Use this, while still in session1, to kill session2.

```
tmux kill-session -t session2
```

You should remain within session1. And if you should no longer see session2 in your session list.

Comment: How to kill the same session where I am typing this?

Comment: Ah. I see. You want to exit the current session and allow tmux to shift you over to a different, active session. Apologies I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Helpful to me. Switch to a different session first if necessary, then `<prefix>:kill-session -t other-session`